# Understanding asp.net core identity template login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In Visual Studio 2017, create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project, changing authentication to Individual User Accounts (so using ASP.NET Core Identity).

In the created project, there is an AccountController. In the [HttpGet] Login method, there is the following:

```
// Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(_externalCookieScheme);
```

I'm just trying to understand the authentication process a bit better. So my questions are:

1. What does this code do?
2. Why is it included in this method?
3. If I do not include this in my own login method, under what circumstances will I encounter a problem, and what will the problem be?

Comment: what it does in this comment: Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process

Answer (score 1):

In identity you can use external login like Microsoft, Google or Facebook and this method insures that you are not logged in with these services before authenticating user.
just if you use external login, include this line in your `Login` action otherwise you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks. So the code logs the current user out of the application if logged in with an external identity provider. It is included in this method because otherwise the user could be logged in with both the external provider and the application login provider at the same time? What is the result if this happens?